# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ekkoLightbox is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to use ekkolightbox on my wordpress site but every time I select an image I get the response.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ekkoLightbox is not a function
```

My guess was that I wasn't importing the library properly through cdn, But I cant quite figure out what I did wrong.

**Here is a shortened version of my code.**

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="https://unsplash.it/1200/768.jpg?image=251" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="example-gallery" data-type="image">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/600.jpg?image=251" class="img-fluid">
    </a>
  </div>
  
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
                  //alert("clicked"); //to test this function ran
                  event.preventDefault();
                  $(this).ekkoLightbox();
              });
          });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: are you getting any console errors?

Answer (score 2):

Use Bootstrap 4 for ekkoLightbox, check reference [here](https://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/)

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="https://unsplash.it/1200/768.jpg?image=251" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="example-gallery">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/600.jpg?image=251" class="img-fluid">
    </a>
  </div>
  
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
        //alert("clicked"); //to test this function ran
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).ekkoLightbox();
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is due because you not load **Bootstrap** `jquery` file.
Try to add the script file into you head `html` page.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).ekkoLightbox();
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="https://unsplash.it/1200/768.jpg?image=251" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="example-gallery" data-type="image">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/600.jpg?image=251" class="img-fluid">
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to work for me when I click run code snippet

Answer (score 0):

This code will solve your problem

```
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <a id="test1" href="https://unsplash.it/1200/768.jpg?image=251" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="example-gallery" data-type="image">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/600.jpg?image=251" class="img-fluid">
    </a>
  </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
                  //alert("clicked"); //to test this function ran
                  event.preventDefault();
                  console.log("HERE");
                  $("#test1").ekkoLightbox();
              });
          });
  </script>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5qmsgf3z/

bootstrap is dependecy for ekko lightbox

Answer (score 0):

You missed adding the bootstrap files (js and css) , also for this lightbox to function correctly you need the css file provided by this library

Please find below the jsfiddle link for working copy of your code

```
   $(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {

              $(this).ekkoLightbox();
              event.preventDefault();

          });
 //     });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/antipotter2006/g0qmf4rb/

Comment: I already have bootstrap 4 working in my project. Do I need to reference it again?